# Change the names of a field

Tags: vba, rename, microsoft-access-2007

I am looking for a way to change field names in Access.

I am importing data through a macro, from text files. Which i then review through a crystal report. Now, sometimes, the report needs to read the field which I imported at field 7 instead of field 5. So I dont want to restructure the whole import process because I am often working on imports for 500000-1,000,000 records and importing that many records from a text file takes around 5-9 minutes each. I'd really rather only do the import once and switch the field names if this is one of those times. So far I've just been right click rename-ing.

Is there a way for me to click a macro and Rename Field5 -> FieldTemp, Field7 -> Field5, and FieldTemp -> Field7

Ultimately I need to rename Field5 <-> Field7. Suggestions?

UPDATE: I've found [this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/change-field-names-table-w-macro-t1629486.html) but I'm not sure how to implement that. Would that work like I think it will? If so, how do I get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with VBA and a keyboard shortcut assigned to your code.

```
Public Function swapFieldNames(table, name1, name2)

    '## Close & save the table in case its open or else you can't rename fields
    DoCmd.Close acTable, CurrentDb().TableDefs(table).Name, acSaveYes

    '## Save all touched field names to temporarily variables for later use
    temp1 = CurrentDb().TableDefs(table).Fields(name1).Name
    temp2 = CurrentDb().TableDefs(table).Fields(name2).Name

    '## Rename them to unique names because duplicate names are not allowed
    CurrentDb().TableDefs(table).Fields(name1).Name = "#$%temp1%$#"
    CurrentDb().TableDefs(table).Fields(name2).Name = "#$%temp2%$#"

    '## Rename them again and do the switch
    CurrentDb().TableDefs(table).Fields("#$%temp1%$#").Name = temp2
    CurrentDb().TableDefs(table).Fields("#$%temp2%$#").Name = temp1

    '## Open the table to view the result
    DoCmd.OpenTable CurrentDb().TableDefs(table).Name

End Function
```

I uploaded a [demo database](http://ge.tt/7nwxf1s/v/0) where you can press <kbd>F3</kbd> to swap the field names "field5" and "field7"

[image]

#### Step-by-step

1. Open your Access database and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to bring up the VBA editor
2. On the left pane right-click on your database name and insert a module
3. On the right pane, paste the above code and save it as e.g `VBA swap module`
4. Follow [Microsoft's guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/run-an-access-macro-by-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-HA010239111.aspx) on how to use AutoKeys for a quick way to execute your code

   - On the Create tab, click Macro (or the arrow below Module and then Macro)
   - On the Design tab, in the Show/Hide group, click Macro Names to display the Macro Name column
   - In the Macro Name column, insert the key to which you want to assign the action

     ```
     Macro Name      Key or keyboard shortcut
     ^A or ^4        CTRL+A or CTRL+4
     {F1}            F1
     ^{F1}           CTRL+F1
     +{F1}           SHIFT+F1
     ```
   - In the Action column, add the action RunCode that runs when your key is pressed
   - In the Arguments column, insert `swapFieldNames("table1", "field5", "field7")` or whatever you have named your module. Here you also define which table should be used for renaming and what field names should be swapped
     [image]
   - Click Save or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and name the macro "AutoKeys". Only with this name, Access will know that it should assign a shortcut when reopened

---

*Hint:* Don't confuse the terms "macro" and "module". For Access, a macro has nothing to do with VBA as you may think. VBA functions and subroutines are called "modules" and macros are a container where you can define multiple actions like "open this table, filter for value XY and delete all entries"

Comment: I skipped the F3 shortcut and ran it directly from a macro. But still OH SO PERFECTT!!